# Where to start with JSP, Struts2 and CRUD?

Tags: jsp, struts2, crud

I was wondering if anyone had a recommendation on where to start with JSP development using Struts2, with a target of creating CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete) applications.

I have a few links that I found through Google, but I am looking for some quick advice before I start some serious learning.   All I have done up to this point is experiment with JSP, JSTL, and Hibernate a little.   I use Eclipse with JBoss5 as a platform but I also like Tomcat (if thats possible).

Comment: ... any particular reasons for Struts2? ... have you looked at Spring? Goes hand in glove with Hibernate since you mentioned it. Something to think about if you're starting with a clean slate.

Comment: ... I said 'Spring' and kept it vague and general. I was just curious why Struts2 at this point in time, not knocking it down. Maybe he's assigned to a project?... thinks about picking up a framework? ... who knows, that's what simple questions are to me.

Answer (score 2):

I found these two sites helpful when I was starting with Struts2:

1. http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-tutorial.html
2. http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/struts-2-tutorials/

They include examples of Struts2 + Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

My Best advise is to download sample applications from Struts2 official site.it will help you to get the initial things and other required start up.
If you want to get ideas about Struts2 tags these sample applications are good to start and rest you can keep adding while you learning this.
regarding CRUD operation all you have to get familiar with Struts2 MVC work flow and how to do your underlying DB operations are completely independent of Struts2

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorials4u.net/struts2-tutorial/struts2_crud_example.html

is the best example of struts 2 i have ever seen